# IndexError: tuple index out of range while accessing numpy ndarray shape

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray, index-error

I am getting

```
Index error: Tuple index out of range while doing one-hot encoding for smile string at line: 
    if ans.shape[1]<length:
```

example:

```
smiles_string= ['C', 'C', '1', '=', 'C', 'C', '(', '=', 'C', 'N', '=', 'C', '1', 'C', '2', '=', 'C', 'C', '(', '=', 'N', 'C', '=', 'C', '2', ')', 'C', ')', 'C', 'C', '(', '=', 'O', ')', 'N', 'C', '3', '=', 'N', 'C', '=', 'C', '(', 'C', '=', 'C', '3', ')', 'C', '4', '=', 'N', 'C', '=', 'C', 'N', '=', 'C', '4']
```

```
char_list=['7', '2', '.', 'Br', 'Pt', '=', '[', 'F', '(', ')', 'O', '6', 'S', '5', '1', 'I', ']', '+', '8', '#', 'C', '3', 'B', '9', 'Cl', 'P', '-', '4', 'N']
```

```
def onehot_encode(char_list, smiles_string, length):
    encode_row = lambda char: map(int, [c == char for c in smiles_string])
    print(encode_row)
    ans = np.array(map(encode_row, char_list))
    if ans.shape[1] < length:
        residual = np.zeros((len(char_list), length - ans.shape[1]), dtype=np.int8)
        ans = np.concatenate((ans, residual), axis=1)
    return ans
```

I tried debugging and I found, shape of ans array is (), which should not happen.

If anyone can give an idea about how to map this and solve the error, would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `.shape()` on something that has no shape.

```py
print(ans)
```

```
Out[1]: <map object at 0x000001E9352B8908>
```

Comment: Yes, that I tried printing, can you help me figure out why there is nothing being stored in an array object after mapping?

Comment: Your question had to do with tuples, arrays, and shapes. I suggest you make a new question about how the `map()` function works for your next issue.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.